# A question regarding Theorem 1.7.2 from James Norris' book on Markov Chains.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

This is regarding theorem 1.7.2 from this page: [https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s17.pdf](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Markov/s17.pdf)

So we let $I$ be finite and assume for some $i\in I$ that $$p_{ij}^{(n)}\to \pi_j\text{ as }n\to \infty\quad \forall j\in I.$$We then want to show that $\pi=(\pi_i)_{i\in I}$ is a invariant distribution. He uses the fact that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}p_{ij}^{(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\in I}p_{ik}^{(n)}p_{kj}.$$My reasoning is that since $\lim_{n\to \infty}p_{ij}^{(n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}p_{ij}^{(n+1)}$ which is the same as going from $i$ to $k$ ($k\in I$ is random) in $n$ steps and then from $k$ to $j$ in $1$ step, thus we get the equality. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  You have $p_{ij}^{(n+1)} = \sum_{k \in I} p_{ik}^{(n)}p_{kj}$ for all $n$ (by the law of total probability). Then take a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Here I am assuming $I$ is the finite set of all possible states.